# custom serilization in GSON library for list

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

I am using custom serialization/deserialization in GSON. for that i have custom gsonAdapter. i am using custom because of difference in property names.

My class :

```
public class Emp {
  String name;
  String age;
}
```

and my json payload :

```
{
 "xyz/abc/name": "abc",
 "xyz/abc/age": "10"
}
```

now i am having problem while converting my list of json to class.

```
[{
 "xyz/abc/name": "abc",
 "xyz/abc/age": "10"
},
{
 "xyz/abc/name": "xyz",
 "xyz/abc/age": "20"
}]
```

tried using

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Emp>>(){}.getType();
List<Emp> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType)
```

but it returns Emp object with all fields initialized as null.

so not able to figure out what else i need to do, if anyone can throw light on the parts i am missing.

Comment: Your example does not use that custom gson adapter? What is the actual JSON you are testing? Having fields name & age? I mean is the field name really `xyz/abc/name` or are there three possibilities --xyz, abc, name for that fiedll in json?

Comment: @pirho Thanks for comment, I have figured out my mistake, by using (& just to info field name are URI's) TypelistType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Emp>>(){}.getType();  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Emp.class, new EmpGsonAdapter()).create();